# How can I grab information using PHP?

Tags: php

I need to grab the list of names and descriptions of a website for indexing purposes. How can I do this using PHP? I would think I would have to use DOM correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is the best way. I would recommend using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). You can do spiffy stuff like this:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Whatever you do, [do not try parsing HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).